# Map of type map[*rsa.PublicKey]*rsa.Privatekey has values, but returns nil

Tags: go, pointers, hashmap, dereference

I have a struct holding the title type definitions. I created a method that should return a value in the map, but it's getting nil. I suspect it's because of the way it's handling pointers, but I'm not sure where or how it's going wrong. What's happening?

Here's the snippet with some extra I had thrown in to see what was happening:

```
func (s *stctClientPubKeys) GetServerPrivateKey(keyClientPubkey *rsa.PublicKey) *rsa.PrivateKey {

var keyPrivateKey *rsa.PrivateKey

s.RLock()
keyPrivateKey = s.mpClientPubKeys[keyClientPubkey]
s.RUnlock()

// TODO Remove this
fmt.Print("KEYINSTRUCT ")
fmt.Println(keyPrivateKey)
s.RLock()
fmt.Print("WHOLEMAPINSTRUCT ")
fmt.Println(s.mpClientPubKeys)
for k, v := range s.mpClientPubKeys {
    chnLogging <- "GetServerPrivateKey(): Recv N = " + keyClientPubkey.N.String()
    chnLogging <- "GetServerPrivateKey(): Key N  = " + k.N.String()
    chnLogging <- "GetServerPrivateKey(): Val N  = " + v.PublicKey.N.String()
}
s.RUnlock()

return keyPrivateKey
}
```

What gets printed in an example run?

```
KEYINSTRUCT <nil>
WHOLEMAPINSTRUCT map[0xc00021e000:0xc0000644e0]
GetServerPrivateKey(): Recv N = 284429934903843367309<cut>
GetServerPrivateKey(): Key N  = 284429934903843367309<cut>
GetServerPrivateKey(): Val N  = 238865868438483289364<cut>
```

The end result when I try to access the returned private key, which you can see is nil, is of course:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x53ce07]
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not deferencing a nil pointer within [rsa.PublicKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey) struct? If `N` is nil, `N.string()` will panic.

Comment: Are you extremely [sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67058355/using-msgp-with-interfaces-and-maps-in-go/67058735#67058735) that `keyClientPubkey` is the same exact pointer you used to set the map value? Map access uses `==` operator to test equality, with all the rules attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to [by blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258964/map-of-type-maprsa-publickeyrsa-privatekey-has-values-but-returns-nil#comment118894466_67258964), this is likely because you are storing a pointer in the map, and the public key that is in the map is semantically equivalent but is not `==` the index.

You don't say how you're getting the arguments for your function, but assuming this is in a server of some kind where the private key is parsed from the wire or from a file, you will be getting a newly allocated object.  That will appear somewhere else in memory from the one that is referenced in your map, and so the pointers will be different even if the modulus and exponent are the same.  The type has an [Equal method](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey.Equal) that can be used for comparison, because `==` will not work.

There are two simple-ish ways to get the behavior that I suspect you intend:

1. Use a slice and iterate through, calling [`.Equal(keyClientPubkey)`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey.Equal) on each, instead of a map.  This is probably fine as long as you have less than, say, hundreds of public keys.  (a benchmark can tell you the exact breakpoint in your environment)
2. Create a `toMapKey` helper function that takes a `*rsa.PublicKey` and returns something comparable (e.g. a string) that can be used as a key.  A simple version would be something like `return fmt.Sprintf("n=%x|e=%x", pk.N, pk.E)`.  Using that, you can store and retrieve public keys based on the string representation.

NOTE: I would not recommend either of the above approaches if this is a security sensitive code path (e.g. if an adversary could trigger it at will), as you are potentially leaking timing information.  Ask a security expert for help if this is the case :).  If you're just doing this during startup or something, it's probably fine.

---

Spec references:

- [map types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)
- [map indexing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)
- [comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)